# Adding square SDK as dependency in Swift 4, Xcode 9

Tags: square-connect

I am looking for help doing this step in Xcode 9, Swift 4:

Git Submodules
Checkout the submodule with git submodule add https://github.com/square/SquarePointOfSaleSDK-iOS.git, drag SquarePointOfSaleSDK.xcodeproj to your project, and add SquarePointOfSaleSDK as a build dependency.

I simply have no idea how to do this - and the examples I found have not worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am dead in the water.

Thanks, Craig

Answer (score 0):

You need a git repo in order to run that command. By default, Xcode will create a git repo for you in your project, so you can simply open your terminal, navigate to your project directory and run:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/square/SquarePointOfSaleSDK-iOS.git
```

This will copy "SquarePointOfSaleSDK-iOS" to your directory. Then, in Finder, you can simply open "SquarePointOfSaleSDK-iOS", drag "SquarePointOfSaleSDK.xcodeproj" to above your project in Xcode. It will ask if you want to save as a Workspace, you should say yes. Then, in Xcode, click on the root of your project, and under "General" - "Linked Frameworks and Libraries", hit the "+" and choose "SquarePointOfSaleSDK.framework".

After that, go ahead and do a build to make sure everything is working, and then you should have access to the SDK within your project.

Comment: Thanks, but ... Tried and got this - still stuck! Craigs-Mac-mini:SquareTest craigcurphey$ ls
AppDelegate.swift  GoogleService-Info.plist
Assets.xcassets   Info.plist
Base.lproj   ViewController.swift
Craigs-Mac-mini:SquareTest craigcurphey$ git submodule add https://github.com/square/SquarePointOfSaleSDK-iOS.git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: OK so you told XCode to not make a git repo for your project. In order to set up a git repo, you can simply open Terminal and navigate to your project and type "git init" and hit enter. After that, try the "git submodule add github.com/square/SquarePointOfSaleSDK-iOS.git" again.